# If $\lim_n f_n(x_n)=f(x)$ for every $x_n \to x$ then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

This is a self-posed question, so I do not know the answer and I would like to know what you think about.

> Let $f,f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous functions. Assume that for every sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converging to a point $x\in [0,1]$, we have
>   $$\lim_n f_n(x_n)=f(x).$$
>   Can we say that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $[0,1]$?

First of all, do you think the question is well-posed? I'm stuck in thinking about it and I don't manage to prove it neither to find a counterexample. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The result is true and this might be one of the few situations where going for a proof by contradiction really helps. Hence, let us assume that $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to $f$. This means that...

Comment: The mode of convergence you ask about is well-established and is called *[continuous convergence](http://planetmath.org/ATheoremAboutContinuousConvergence.html)* and I think @did's hint should be very helpful (don't forget to use compactness of $[0,1]$!)

Comment: @did: I tried to follow your advice but is kind of stuck.

Comment: How did you write down the hypothesis that $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to $f$? If you have a problem with this, you may first write down the hypothesis that $(f_n)$ does converge uniformly to $f$, then negate this. So: what does it mean to say that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$?

Comment: Hopefully fixed by now, but may still have problems.

Comment: @user32240 Although I forgot to add your name, my last comment above is directed at you.

Comment: @did: as I expected it was wrong. Yes I was aware of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this is true:

Suppose that the convergence $f_n \to f$ is *not* uniform but that $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_n)$ for every convergent sequence $x_n\to x$ in $[0,1]$.

After passing to a subsequence of the $f_n$ we may assume that there is $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert f(x) - f_n(x) \rvert \gt \varepsilon$. This implies that there is a sequence of points $x_n \in [0,1]$ such that $\lvert f(x_n) - f_n(x_n) \rvert \gt \varepsilon$ for each $n$. After passing to further subsequences, we may assume that $x_n \to x \in [0,1]$ by compactness of $[0,1]$. But then we're in trouble: our hypotheses tell us that 
$$\tag{$\ast$}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert f(x) - f_n(x_n)\rvert = 0,
$$
which is incompatible with $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ and $\lvert f_n(x_n) - f(x)\rvert \gt \varepsilon$.

More formally: continuity of $f$ ensures together with $x_n \to x$ that there is $N$ such that $\lvert f(x) - f(x_n)\rvert \lt \varepsilon/2$ for all $n \geq N$ so that the triangle inequality gives us for all $n \geq N$ that
$$
\begin{align*}
\lvert f_n(x_n) - f(x) \rvert &= \lvert [f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)] - [f(x) - f(x_n)]\rvert \\
& \geq \underbrace{\lvert f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)\rvert}_{\gt \varepsilon} - \underbrace{\lvert f(x) - f(x_n)\rvert}_{\lt \varepsilon/2} \\& \gt \varepsilon/2 \gt 0,
\end{align*}
$$
which is absurd in view of $(\ast)$.

---

**Comments:**

1. The mode of convergence $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$ for all $x_n \to x$ is called *continuous convergence*. Continuity of the $f_n$ is never used in the above argument. In fact, $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$ for all $x_n \to x$ ensures continuity of $f$ independently of the continuity of the $f_n$ (exercise).
2. You can find a generalization of the above result and a more detailed discussion in the section *Compact and continuous convergence* (Chapter 3, §1, section 5) starting on [page 98](http://books.google.com/books?id=CC0dQxtYb6kC&pg=PA98) in R. Remmert's *[Theory of complex functions](http://books.google.com/books?id=CC0dQxtYb6kC)*. The precise result reads that $f_n$ converges to $f$ continuously if and only if $f$ is continuous and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact sets. More details in *loc. cit.* (don't miss the historical notes preceding and following that section!).

Comment: I posted this answer simultaneously with did's hint but I then deleted it to give the OP some time to think about it. I hope it's fine to show it now.

Comment: Basically, I have no opinion here. Let me mention that Romeo probably did not even **see** my two comments (the first one addressed to him and the second one answering @user32240's query), nicely completed by your own comment (mentioning compactness).

Comment: This is a very clear proof. Thank you.

Comment: Is the converse true? That is, if we are given that $ f_n (x_n)$ converges UNIFORMLY to $f(x)$ and the sequence of points $(x_n) \rightarrow x$, then does $f_n(x_n) \rightarrow f (x)$ [pointwise convergence]? If so, can anyone help me out by providing a proof. I am having a hard time thinking that the converse is true.

Comment: @t.b.: $\{f_n\}$ does not converge to $f$ implies  $\exists \epsilon >0$ such that for some subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ , there is a sequence $\{x_k\}$ in domain such that $|f_{n_k}(x_k)-f(x_k)| \ge \epsilon$ ; but how does one ensure that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\ge \epsilon$ , as used in the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a classical theorem by [Dini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) that says this is possible when $f_{i}$ are  monotonically increasing.

We now assume $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ pointwise and $f,f_{n}$ are all continuous but the limit is not uniform. Thus there is some $\epsilon$ such that $\forall N$ there is some $n\ge N$ such that $$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|> \epsilon$$ for some $x\in [0,1]$.

Now since $f_{i},f$ are uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, for $\epsilon_{1}=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ we have a list of $\delta_{i}$s such that $0< \delta_{i}\le 1$ and $|f_{i}(x)-f_{i}(y)|\le \epsilon_{1}$ for $|x-y|\le \delta_{i}$. Consider the interval $U_{i}=[0,\delta_{i}]$, I claim $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \bigcap U_{i}\not=\emptyset$. Suppose $\cap_{i=N} U_{i}=\emptyset$, then $f_{i}$ would have nontrivial variation $$\lim_{x \rightarrow y} |f(x)-f(y)|=0$$ a fact contradicting they are being continuous. Thus let $U=[0,\delta_{A}]$ be the intersection, and let $\delta_{B}$ be the corresponding value for $f$. We choose $\delta=\min[\delta_{A},\delta_{B}]$.

We now assume the counterexample in the beginning. For fixed $y$ such that $|x-y|\le \delta$ we can choose $N$ large enough such that $$|f(y)-f_{n}(y)|\le \epsilon/3$$ for any $n\ge N$. If it turns out $N$ is greater than the initial $n$ we chose, we may switch to a different $n$ guaranteed to exist by the hypothesis.

We have the estimate that $$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\le |f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|+|f_{n}(y)-f(y)|+|f_{n}(y)-f_{n}(x)\le \epsilon$$ which contradicts the hypothesis we had earlier. So the convergence is uniform afterall.

Comment: In fact the desired result in the OP is true.

Comment: My example has serious problem at point 1. Let me try to modify it.

Comment: @t.b.:can you check if my 'proof' is correct?

Comment: No, this doesn't really work this way. 1) the OP assumes something *much stronger* than pointwise convergence. 2) By your definitions you certainly have $0 \in \bigcap_{i=N}^\infty [0,\delta_i]$ and you probably try to argue that there is $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that $[0,\varepsilon]$ is in this intersection: so you're trying to establish *equicontinuity* of the $f_n$, right? 3) I don't understand what the sentence including "nontrivial variation" is supposed to mean. 4) Sorry I am lost in the last two paragraphs: what is the $x$ doing? How do you get from $|x-y|\lt \delta$ to uniform conv.?

Comment: See my answer for a detailed argument.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistakes. I was actually wondering why it did not got downvoted for mistake 1 and 2 is obvious. I mean total bounded variation should be 0 for any continuous function.